# parsing dates from strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, date-parsing

I have a list of strings in python like this

```
['AM_B0_D0.0_2016-04-01T010000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D3.7_2016-04-13T215000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D10.3_2017-03-17T110000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D0.7_2016-10-21T104000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D4.4_2016-08-05T151000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D0.0_2016-04-01T010000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D3.7_2016-04-13T215000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D10.3_2017-03-17T110000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D0.7_2016-10-21T104000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D4.4_2016-08-05T151000.flac.h5']
```

I want to parse only the date and time (for example, 2016-08-05 15:10:00 )from these strings.

So far I used a for loop like the one below but it's very time consuming, is there a better way to do this?

```
for files in glob.glob("AM_B0_*.flac.h5"):
    if files[11]=='_':
        year=files[12:16]
        month=files[17:19]
        day= files[20:22]
        hour=files[23:25]
        minute=files[25:27]
        second=files[27:29]
        tindex=pd.date_range(start= '%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d' %(int(year),int(month), int(day), int(hour), int(minute), int(second)), periods=60, freq='10S') 

    else:
        year=files[11:15]
        month=files[16:18]
        day= files[19:21]
        hour=files[22:24]
        minute=files[24:26]
        second=files[26:28]
        tindex=pd.date_range(start= '%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d' %(int(year), int(month), int(day), int(hour), int(minute), int(second)), periods=60, freq='10S')
```

Comment: You could use a regex, but I would expect Python's base string operations (i.e. what you are currently using) would be faster than a regex.

Comment: Why not just insert required symbols (:) and remove the unwanted ones (first 11 and the T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (based on the 2nd last '-', no need of if-else case):

```
filesall = ['AM_B0_D0.0_2016-04-01T010000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D3.7_2016-04-13T215000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D10.3_2017-03-17T110000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D0.7_2016-10-21T104000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D4.4_2016-08-05T151000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D0.0_2016-04-01T010000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D3.7_2016-04-13T215000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D10.3_2017-03-17T110000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D0.7_2016-10-21T104000.flac.h5',
 'AM_B0_D4.4_2016-08-05T151000.flac.h5']

def find_second_last(text, pattern):
    return text.rfind(pattern, 0, text.rfind(pattern))

for files in filesall:
    start = find_second_last(files,'-') - 4 # from yyyy- part
    timepart = (files[start:start+17]).replace("T"," ")
    #insert 2 ':'s
    timepart = timepart[:13] + ':' + timepart[13:15] + ':' +timepart[15:]
    # print(timepart)
    tindex=pd.date_range(start= timepart, periods=60, freq='10S')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Place of using file[11] as hard coded go for last or 2nd last index of `_` then use your code then you don't have to write 2 times same code. Or use regex to parse the string.

Comment: Looking at the else case, it's indicated that that underscore may not always be present. It'll be better to use second last '-' instead

Comment: @Jay Shankar Gupta     could you please tell with an example how to do that? I'm new to programming.